# What is the micro-optimal and most elegant way of returning List<string> of elements that occurs only once in other List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

This was an interview question I had today:

> "Given a list of strings, return a list of only the unique strings"

I'm curious about what the Skeet-certified answer would be.

My own answer was

```
public static List<string> sans_repeats ( List<string> input ) 
{
    Dictoinary<string,int> counter = new Dictionary<string,int>();
    List<string> output = new List<string>();
    foreach ( string S in input ) 
    {
       if ( counter.HasKey(S) ) counter[S] = 1;
       else ++count[S];
    }     
    foreach ( KeyValuePair<string,int> entry in counter ) 
       if ( entry.Value == 1 ) output.Add(entry.Key);
    return output;
}
```

and interview said

> "Well, that's one way to do it ..."

in a voice that sounded condescending, as if I was doing something wrong.

- Is there anything logically wrong about it?
- Is there a way to achieve a more memory- and processing-efficient solution?
- Was the interviewer likely looking for a LINQ-esque solution? Why didn't he seem to like mine?
- Is there a way to make this more compact?

Comment: If you add to string index of this string in list, it would be unique, also you can use new GUID()+ yourstring

Comment: Can you please elaborate the meaning of "The Unique string in List<string>", i am curious myself.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed EXAMPLE: { "dog", "cat", "elephant", "dog", "dog" } -> { "cat", "elephant" }

Comment: Oh you meant elements that occurs only once in a list, Right :P

Comment: **Just my opinion:** as an interviewer, I would probably be expecting LINQ solution with remark about performance. It may be less efficient (but not that much, it is linear too), but slight performance improvement is not a reason for "reinventing the wheel" and writing custom function **every time** you work with collections.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev What if my wheel is vastly superior to the one already in use?

Comment: There are a couple of styling and syntax issues with your code, it might also be a reason why the interviewer didn't like it. `sans_repeats` is named incorrectly. `HasKey` is not an actual function (it's named `ContainsKey`). Lack of `{` `}` braces make for poor looking code. Also, when you create a dictionary you have to `Add` and item, then increment the count. Your code looks very much ruby like. So, since you didn't give the LINQ answer plus your code seems like you don't really have experience with C#, it might have contributed to some displeasing to your interviewer.

Comment: @user5572578 Then, it is a good option. However, LINQ isn't much slower than your algorithm. `GroupBy`, `Where` and `ToList` have linear time complexity.

Comment: Please put a clarification/example of `only the unique strings` in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on updated question, here's a way with LINQ:

```
var src = new List<string>() { "dog", "cat", "elephant", "dog", "dog" } ;
src.GroupBy(x => x).Where(y => y.Count() == 1).ToList();
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/NIVZB82559)

Comment: I may have misphrased the question. I meant that the list returned only contains strings that occur once in the original list.

Comment: Ah, awesome! But is that as efficient, considering the unlderying implementations of the LINQ clauses?

Comment: Timewise I suppose you could measure it to be certain.

Comment: This is better than my answer for succinctness.

Comment: Calling `Count()` can be quite expensive if the underlying structure is not an `ICollection` (which you can't know). So I would prefer `!y.Skip(1).Any()` see [demo](http://rextester.com/GVLY44974).

Comment: Shouldn't there be something like `.Select(g => g.Key)` before `ToList` call.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way, use the in-built function:

```
List<string> distinctList = input.Distinct();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb920306(v=vs.90).aspx

Alternatively, check if the current item already exists in the output list and continue if it does:

```
List<string> output = new List<string>();
foreach (string S in input) 
{
    if (output.Contains(S)) continue;       
    output.Add(S);
}
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment that you only want items that occur *once only*:

```
Dictionary<string, int> stringCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (string S in input) 
{
    if (stringCount.ContainsKey(S))
    {
        stringCount[S]++;
    }
    else
    {
        stringCount.Add(S, 1);
    }       
}

var output = stringCount.Where(x => x.Value == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: `input.Distinct()` is `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: I may have not phrased my quesiton correctly. I'm talking about a procedure that only adds elements to the second string if they occur exactly once in the first string.

Comment: @Candide So use `.ToList()` afterwards.

Comment: @user5572578, true. It's a bit more "Linq-y" at the end though.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's an interview question, you need to consider what the interviewer wants from this question.

1. If he wants to know your skills on LINQ, you should give the LINQ code. (like other answers)
2. If he wants to test your algorithm, you need to write pure C style program instead of using built-in library. In this case, your code can be improved because it costs more memory than expected. The variable `output` in your program can be optimized. The input parameter already contains all strings, it's unnecessary to copy it again. Also `counter` is a over-kill, you only need a `int[]` to store the count of elements.
3. Sometimes the interviewer wants to test the interviewee's way of resolving problems. When you are asked this question, you can ask the interviewer:

   (1) Should the returned list the same reference as the input list, or create a new list is acceptable?

   (2) How many times an element occurs at most? If necessary, use `byte[]` to store the count instead of `int[]`.

Comment: How would you use `byte[]` to store the count?

Comment: @CallumLinington If I was told all elements occur at most 100 times. It's just an example.

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to understand why `byte[]` is significant. Why 100 times?

Comment: @CallumLinington It's not that significant. But if you mention this slight improvement in an interview, the interviewer will probably think you always consider carefully and comprehensively before starting to coding.

Answer (score 0):

Linq is a good option, but if you want a collection, why use a `Dictionary` when a `HashSet` is probably more appropriate.

```
var strings = new[] { "a", "a", "b", "c" };
var hash = new HashSet<string>(strings);
hash.Dump(); // a, b, c
```

Comment: See the OP's comment to the question: `{ "dog", "cat", "elephant", "dog", "dog" } -> { "cat", "elephant" }`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another effective way of doing that, using the fact that [HashSet.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx) method actually adds the item and returns true only if the item is not already in the set. The code is self explanatory.

```
var uniqueSet = new HashSet<string>();
var duplicateSet = new HashSet<string>(input.Where(item => !uniqueSet.Add(item)));
var output = input.Where(item => !duplicateSet.Contains(item)).ToList();
```